# Declare a vue template in javascript

Tags: vue.js

I have a scenario in my app where i want to declare a template in javascript. For an example, after I import my template

```
import MyTemplate from "./MyTemplate";
export default {
            components: {MyTemplate},
}
```

Can i declare in a javascript? For example:

```
mounted:function(){ 
        let temp = new MyTemplate() 
}
```

and not in html way

```
<MyTemplate/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you could use a vue object with a render function instead of a single page component

Comment: Thx  for help,  but is there an example where I can follow the process? I am not a Vue expert, it's hard to understand how i do it in my app. When i google a **"Declare a vue template in javascript"** i don't get much of results that i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example utilizing the [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) instead of the typical single-page component:

```js
var SomeElement = {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(
      "h1",
      this.name
    )
  },
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { SomeElement: SomeElement },
  template: "#app-template",
  data: function() {
    return {
      num: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increaseNames: function() {
      this.num += 1;
    },
    decreaseNames: function() {
      if (this.num === 0) return;
      this.num -= 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
    <div>
      <some-element v-for="n in num" :name="'Derek-' + n" :key="n" />
      <button @click="increaseNames">Add another name</button>
      <button @click="decreaseNames">Remove another name</button>
    </div>
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, `SomeElement` is essentially a pure javascript object that is included in the `App` component.

**EDIT**

I included a way to dynamically add elements to the vue template with the built-in [vue methods attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods). Keep in mind that the idea behind using a framework like `vue` is to pre-define your components and then utilize them as much or as little as possible - even dynamically, as is shown in this particular instance.

Comment: Thx, but not sure if this is what i need. I want to call my template later same as i do with class in java. In Java i can create a class and then, i call it from another component by importing it. I have a template but what if i need it later to be added dynamically with javascript? For example i have button.vue, can i do just 

**let _btn = new button()**?

Comment: You can always import it and not use it until you need to. That logic should probably be put in the template of the component you need it in. Alternatively, you can register global components that can be used anywhere at any time

Comment: So u mean i can do **let element = new SomeElement()** ? When i do it i get an error!

Comment: No, you can do something like `<some-element v-for="n in 10" :name="'derek' + n" />`

Comment: That will create 10 new elements that contain their own data and props

Comment: Thanks Derek, i guess we have no choice. It will be cool if i could just doing  **let element = new SomeElement() ** and then access it through the JS but as i see we cant do it in Vue.

Comment: @VadimKorolov you can use methods to create a new item, I'm updating to show you how now

Comment: Also, @VadimKorolov - keep in mind that every element made through the template is its own "object" (or class, if you'd prefer)

Comment: This way i do most of my logic in vue, the problem is that i am working with nativescript, I have a gallery with 5000 images where i need to display the image depend on user Y scroll, i have to remove the image if the image is not in the user Vue. I have the image template i created **bitmapImage.vue** I was thinking of doing it by ** let img = new bitmapImage()** and then add it to the view if i need it or remove it depends on Y scroll. So as i understand we cant do it in Vue and i have to keep follow Vue logics here... Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: If that's what you're doing, use a computed property to give you the correct image, and only use 1 component